# How to remove a directory and its empty ancestors with Perl?

Tags: perl, rmdir

What is the Perl way of removing a directory and then all ***empty*** **parent** directories up to the first non-empty one? In other words, what could one use instead of:

```
system 'rmdir', '-p', $directory;
```

which, in starting with `d`, would first remove `d` and then `c`, and then `b`, but not `a`, since `a` would still contain `x`, like this:

```
a
a/b
a/b/c
a/b/c/d
a/x
```

resulting in

```
a
a/x
```

It's not the built-in `rmdir`, as it can only remove a **single** directory. ([doc](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rmdir.html))

It's not `finddepth ( sub {rmdir}, '.' )`, using `File::Find`, as it removes **children**, not parents. ([doc](http://duramecho.com/ComputerPrograms/DeleteEmptyDirectories/))

It's not the `remove_tree` function of the `File::Path` module either, since it not only removes children directories but **files** as well. ([doc](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html))

Notice, `remove_tree` and `finddepth` work in the opposite direction of Bash `rmdir --parent`.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "empty parent directories", perhaps with an example? Being a parent directory implies a child directory which implies it's not empty.

Comment: I meant how to remove a directory and its ancestors.

Comment: So we can ignore the word "empty"?

Comment: Nope. If you remove a directory, its parent may become empty.

Comment: Hang on ... why would it not remove `b` in your example?

Comment: yes, sorry, let me change the example

Comment: @zdim No. `remove_tree` would remove `x` but `x` is not an ancestor of `d`

Comment: @n.r Right, I see -- I had thought that there was an option.  Removing that comment ...

Comment: @zdim Also notice that `remove_tree` deletes directories and **files**, that is, it's not meant to remove empty directories, but everything it finds downwards into a tree.

Comment: @n.r Yes, it works like `rm -rf`.  I mis-remembered that it had an option to only remove empty, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
use Path::Tiny qw( path );

my $p = path('a/b/c/d');

while (!$p->is_rootdir()) {
    if (!rmdir($p)) {
        last if $!{ENOTEMPTY};
        die("Can't remove \"$p\": $!\n");
    }

    $p = $p->parent;
}
```

Notes:

- Efficient. By checking the result of `rmdir` instead of using `->children` or `->iterator`, this solution is avoids needless calls to `readdir`.
- No race conditions. Unlike the solutions that use `readdir` (via `->children` or `->iterator`), this solution doesn't suffer from a race condition.
- This solution also avoids the redundant `-d` check used by an earlier solution.
- This solution, unlike those before it, will handle a tree that's empty except for the directories to remove.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK this doesn't exist. You can write it yourself fairly easily with [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny). It's a simple recursive function.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

use Carp;
use Path::Tiny;
use autodie;

sub Path::Tiny::rmdir_if_empty {
    my $self = shift;

    # Stop when we reach the parent.
    # You can't rmdir('.') anyway.
    return if $self eq '.';

    croak "$self is not a directory" if !$self->is_dir;

    # Stop if the directory contains anything.
    # I use an iterator to avoid a possibly very long list.
    my $iter = $self->iterator;
    return if defined $iter->();

    # rmdir will not delete a non-empty directory, a second safeguard
    rmdir $self;

    return $self->parent->rmdir_if_empty;
}

path("a/b/c/d")->rmdir_if_empty;
```

Comment: It would stop at `a`.

Comment: @n.r. Turns out it would stop, but only because `rmdir('.')` fails. I fixed it to stop at the root of the given path, empty or not. Now `path("c/d")->rmdir_if_empty` won't delete `b`.

Comment: @ikegami To make the recursion work better, and because Path::Tiny doesn't subclass well (peek inside `Path::Tiny->new` to see why). Adding a method is safe-ish, safer than altering an existing one. You can do it as a function. YMMV.

Comment: The non-intrusive solution (`sub rmdir_if_empty { ... return rmdir_if_empty($self->parent); } rmdir_if_empty(path("a/b/c/d"));`) recurses just as easily. Noone suggested altering an existing method.

Comment: Needless `readdir`. Race condition (from the use of `readdir`). Doesn't handle a drive that just contains `a/b/c/d`.

Comment: @ikegami Can you provide any details about those assertions? Ahh, I see your answer now, very clever!

Answer (score 3):

As always, using my favorite [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny)

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use Path::Tiny;
use autodie;

my $p = path('a/b/c/d');     # starting
die "$p is not a dir" unless -d $p;

while( ! $p->children ) {    # if it is empty
        rmdir $p;            # remove it
        $p = $p->parent;     # go upward
}
```

Comment: Needless initial `-d` (since `->children` will perform the same check). Needless `readdir`. Race condition (from the use of `readdir`). Doesn't handle a drive that just contains `a/b/c/d`.